# JsonResult does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS through a tutorial when came across this problem. Some suggested adding of a constructor like

```
public JsonResult()
{
}
```

This didnt work either.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ReactWithMVCPart1.Properties
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult Getmessage()
        {
            return new JsonResult { Data = "Hello World. I am from server-side" };
        }
    }
}
```

Tutorial link for reference : http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/02/hello-world-in-reactjs.html

Comment: From your code you appear to be using ASP.NET Core MVC but the tutorial is for "traditional" ASP.NET MVC. There may be differences between the two frameworks in terms of how the classes are defined and used. Check the docs for .NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1 to see how you can use a JsonResult . I'd expect that `return new JsonResult ({ Data = "Hello World. I am from server-side" });` ought to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding on ADyson's answer: What worked for me was

```
return new JsonResult ( new { Data = "Hello World. I am from server-side" } );
```

or, a little more usefull:

```
JsonResult result = new JsonResult ( new {} );
```

You can now do some work, and set a useful response with

```
result.Value = new { success = false };
```

Comment: The error now appears with 'JsonResult does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument'

Comment: What framework are you using? And/or what json library?